# Best practice for an optional method that I want to call in Start()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, abstract-class

I've created an abstract class called `PlayerComponent` for all components that need to interact with my `PlayerController` to inherit from. This class holds the reference to the `PlayerController`, the `Player` (responsible for input), and I wanted to add a bit of functionality by setting up a method to trigger when the `PlayerController` "lands" on the ground.

```
public abstract class PlayerComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected static PlayerController playerController;
    protected Player player; //the Rewired player

    protected void Start()
    {
        player = ReInput.players.GetPlayer(0);

        if (playerController == null)
            playerController = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();

        playerController.onLanding.AddListener(OnPlayerLanding);
    }

    public abstract void OnPlayerLanding();
}
```

In `Start()`, I subscribe an abstract method to the `UnityEvent` that the `PlayerController` invokes upon landing. It works great and I quite like how I've structured this, *but* in practice, I ended up creating some `PlayerComponent`s that don't need the `OnPlayerLanding` method at all. Since its an abstract method, these `PlayerComponent`s are required to have this blank method sitting there, and possibly taking up resources by being invoked (idk if that's even true, is it?). Is there a best practice for how I can make this method optional? Should I make an additional class to act in between the 2 which is responsible for making the Landing calls, and have only the components that require it inherit from it? I'm a little out of my comfort zone but trying to learn how to do this nice and tidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make method by virtual, and override it for need in heir.

```
    public abstract class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public virtual void Start()
        {
            // Base code
        }

        public virtual void Mehtod()
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Make Start() virtual too. To call the method where necessary, override `Start()` with the base implementation and complete the subscription

```
public abstract class SomeHeir : SomeClass
    {
        protected static PlayerController playerController;

        public override void Start()
        {
            base.Start();

            playerController.onLanding.AddListener(OnPlayerLanding);
        }
    }
```

You can virtualize all MonoBenaviour methods

Comment: Ooh thank you, that solves the need to override it in every heir class. I have one more question- in that case, should I call the virtual method in the Start() method of the heir? Otherwise I'm still calling the empty virtual method in cases where it hasn't been overridden.

Comment: I'm edit now my answer wait, please

Comment: Look now my answer

Comment: You need to remove `AddListener` from the virtual method and realization this in override

Comment: Sorry for my English, if I have errors, English don't my native language

Comment: That makes sense, thanks again! No worries, your English was understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Awake` for its own initializations not with start. If you only use start for it and if you depend on another classes you will highly get chance error of null exceptions.

`Start` is meant to be used for dependency of another classes because any `Start` method will be called after all awake methods called.

Simply make Awake virtual and override it.

And most of the time you would want subscribe events at `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` because disabled GameObjects will be still called unless its never meant to disabled.

Check [Order of execution for event functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).